# Creating a table failed even though I checked for syntax errors

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am creating a fake table for just practice as I am taking Intro to SQL. I looked up at the MySQL Reference guide on their website for more information on `VARCHAR` and `NUMBER`.

When I try to `create table`, I get an error message `Error Code: 1064.` I know I checked my syntax and made sure to look for missing commas or spelling typos, but everything is correct. I am clueless as to why am I not able to create a table! This is starting to annoy the heck out of me!

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
(REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15),
 FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
 CITY CHAR(15),
 STATE CHAR(2),
 POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5),
 COMMISSION NUMBER(7,2),
 RATE NUMBER(3,2) );
```

**OUTPUT**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
'NUMBER(7,2),
RATE NUMBER(3,2) )' at line 8
```

Comment: Perhaps googling MySQL data types would help.

Comment: @P.Salmon Link please?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html

Comment: @Aaron Dietz Gordon Linoff was able to help me. It is because I am following the oracle version of coding and not mysql. My school textbook is using oracle database whereas my teacher recommends that I use MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER` is not a MySQL data type.  You intend `NUMERIC`:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_REP (
 REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15),
 FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
 CITY CHAR(15),
 STATE CHAR(2),
 POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5),
 COMMISSION numeric(7,2),
 RATE numeric(3,2)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11fb890248de678c738cdc22803b6263) is a db<>fiddle.  The confusion probably arises because `NUMBER` *is* an Oracle data type.  Oracle is a company that owns multiple databases, including one called Oracle and one called MySQL.

Comment: Ah I gotcha. My textbook is using an Oracle database and my teacher recommends to use MySQL. Do you have a place where I can reference a "conversion" language from oracle to mysql? That must be why it is confusing to me and why I am not able to execute even though everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: I would love to pick this as a solution but I have to wait a while before I can accept it.

Comment: @Azazel . . . I think you can download a free copy of Oracle to play with.